# susy grid 840 how to set it

Tags: css, sass, susy

I want to position 2 div's. 150px | div width 440px | 100px | div width 440px | 150px . I don't know how to set it. I know it should be simple but this is my first project with susy

```
$susy: (
 columns: 12,
 math: fluid,
 output: float,
 last-flow: to
);

.rounded{
  @include span(6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
//left: 150px;
  top: 224px;
  width: 440px;
  height: 478px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.rounded2 {
  @include span(6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  top: 224px;
  width: 440px;
  height: 478px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }

<div class="newApp">
 <h1>To do list</h1>
 <div class="rounded">
  <ul>
    {{#each tasksToDo}}
        {{>task}}
    {{/each}}
 </ul>
</div>

<h1>Done list</h1>
 <div class="rounded2">
  <ul>
    {{#each taskDone}}
        {{>done}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<template name="done">
<li class="list_item">
    <span class="text">{{title}}</span>
</li>
</template>

<template name="task">
 <li class="list_item">
    <span id="editingTask">{{> editableText collection="tasks"     field="title"}}</span>
    <br>
    <button class="completed">Completed</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTQnZ.jpg

Here is html and pic

Comment: can you share an image to understand what do you want? also de html and if posible post it on codepen.io and share the link.

Comment: http://imgur.com/TRp9iJd    here is what i want and i put html in the original post

Comment: Try to change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` and play with `top` and `left` values, if it not fix your problem, share un example con http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is overriding everything that susy would do for you. Susy sets a width, a float, and margins or padding (for gutters). Here's a [sassmeister demonstration](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9ef4e7ae6b85cafe9edb) of *one way* to get your layout using Susy. There would be any number of other approaches, since Susy is essentially a calculator, and expects you to provide most of the opinions.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 2,
  column-width: 440px,
  gutters: 100/440,
  gutter-position: split,
);

.newApp {
  padding: gutter()*2;
}

.rounded,
.rounded2 {
  @include span(1);
}
```

Currently your `h1` elements are in the way, though. You'll have to wrap them inside the layout blocks. That's just a problem with CSS floats.

Comment: one more question now footer that has few div's(logos inline) and now footer has a size of 590%

Comment: I can't comment on that without seeing the code. any chance you are spanning more than the available number of columns?

Comment: i fixed that.. but I noticed that spacing isn't correct I need 150x440x100x440x150 but yours is 150x440x150x440x150

Comment: Updated to get this right. I actually had `100` for all the gutters, so just had to add more on the edges (see `gutter()*2`).